# How do I restrict the user or ARCamera to inside an area in world space?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I have built a room in the xcode scene editor and I want the user to be able to explore it, but not be able to pass through walls, floor or ceiling.

I've tried adding physics bodies to the pointOfView node that holds the ARCamera and to the walls with no success. Camera passes through still.

Also, I've been trying to access the pointOfView's transform in the `func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame)` method and if it is outside the range of room walls set the appropriate variable back inside the walls. The pointOfView's 4th column, indices 0, 1, 2 which I believe represent position variables x, y, z are always 0.0 and do not update as device moves around. And setting them seems to do nothing.

How can I restrict user/camera to an definitive area in AR?

I am using AR w/ SceneKit.